# Which voice (active/passive) is the following sentence in?

Tags: passive-voice

Is the following sentence in active voice or in passive voice?

Cutting-edge Infosys projects in Artificial Intelligence were highlighted by Vishal Sikka.

Comment: as "by Vishal sikka" is there that is way I am in coufusion

Comment: The subject is the first six words, but that's not what is doing anything (ie not the agent). Look at [this explanation at Grammar-Quizzes.com](http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/passive1b.html).

Comment: Thanks for replying. Could you pls elaborate about "has standard passive voice"?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is in the passive voice and has the standard passive voice form of the patient noun phrase (NP) acting as grammatical subject, with the agent moved into the 'by-' phrase.

This can also be seen by checking to see if it has a corresponding active voice form (noun phrases bracketed for clarity):

> (Vishal Sikka) highlighted (cutting-edge Infosys projects in Artificial Intelligence).

Comment: Isn't there just a chance that the passive construction has been addressed here before? A search here on ELU for 'passive by-phrase' returns 257 hits. As Janus has recently commented, '[Y]ou  should always keep in mind the possibility of duplicates when reading (and answering) a question, and consider how likely a question is to be a duplicate.... This one … very, very likely.'

Comment: Fair enough @EdwinAshworth.